# OSX 10.9 - Eclipse, C++, OpenGL, functions not found

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, opengl

After countless hours of trying to setup OpenGL on Eclipse, I've managed to include all missing libraries, however it still outputs this error many times:

```
expected initializer before '__AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__MAC_10_0_DEP__MAC_10_9' line 255, external location: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Headers/glu.h
```

and also it doesn't recognize any of the glut functions:

```
'glutInit' was not declared in this scope   /Teste  main.cpp    line 9  C/C++ Problem
```

the code is really simple, just to try initiating glut.

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: did you try `#include <glu.h>` ?

Comment: You could always create an Xcode project to do it and compare what the command line produced by Xcode is vs. Eclipse.